# generator object preventing list comprehension

Tags: python, list, generator

I am trying to turn a string into a list of words, then into a list of word lengths. For example:

```
myString = 'this is a test string with test words in it'
myString = myString.split(' ')
myNums = []
for i in range(len(myString)):
    myNums.append(len(myString[i]))
print(myNums)
>>[4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2]
```

I think I should be able to do this using list comprehension, for example:

```
myNums = [len(myString[i] for i in range(len(myString)))]
```

But when I do, I get `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`

I can't figure out where the generator object is, and why it's incompatible with list comprehension. Any tips/suggestions appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have a typo: `len(myString[i]` should be `len(myString[i])`

Comment: And one of the `)` at the end should be removed.

Comment: Shouldn't be myNums = [len(myString[i]) for i in range(len(myString))] ?

Comment: Why not just `[len(s) for s in myString]`?

Comment: ugh yes thank you *facepalm*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your expression by iterating on elements of your list and not on index:

```
myNums = [len(w) for w in myString]
print(myNums)

# Output
[4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2]
```

You can also use functional programming:

```
myNums = list(map(len, myString))
print(myNums)

# Output:
[4, 2, 1, 4, 6, 4, 4, 5, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a misplaced closing parenthesis:

```
myNums = [len(myString[i] for i in range(len(myString)))]
                         ^                             |
                         |___should go there___________|
```